# Quasar set different colors for QDate multiple ranges

Tags: quasar-framework, daterangepicker

I am using [Quasar date picker](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/date#range-selection). I have multiple date ranges and want to set different background colors for each range. I have some ideas about adding color to the `dateRanges` array beside `from` and `to` props like the following code. Is there any way to do something like this?

```
<q-date v-model="dateRanges" range readonly />

dateRanges: [
  {from: '1402/07/08', to: '1402/07/17', color: 'teal'},
  {from: '1402/07/18', to: '1402/07/20', color: 'red'},
  {from: '1402/07/25', to: '1402/07/30', color: 'secondary'}
],
```